# Cannot properly init mysql db (using docker-compose) on google cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-build

I'm currently setting up a build/test pipeline for my app (django) using Google Cloud Build (and testing using `cloud-build-local`).

In order to properly run the tests I need to start a mysql dependency (I use `docker-compose` for this ). The issue is that when running `docker-compose` in a cloud-build step, database init scripts are not properly run, I get a

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-init.sql
ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device.
```

(running docker-compose out of google-cloud-build properly works)

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'dev'
      MYSQL_USER: 'dev'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dev'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - reports-db:/var/lib/mysql-reports
      - ./dev/databases/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-init.sql
      - ... (other init scripts) 
volumes:
  reports-db:
```

And `cloudbuild.yaml` :

```
steps:
...
- id: 'tests-dependencies'
  name: 'docker/compose:1.24.1'
  args: ['up', '-d']
...
```

Files being organized like this:

```
parent_dir/
   dev/
      databases/
         init.sql
   cloudbuild.yaml
   docker-compose.yml
   ...
```

(all commands are run from `parent_dir/`)

When I run

```
cloud-build-local --config=cloudbuild.yaml --dryrun=false .
```

I get a

```
...
Step #2 - "tests-dependencies": mysql_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0-init.sql
Step #2 - "tests-dependencies": mysql_1  | ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device.
...
```

Knowing that running `docker-compose up` directly works properly

I'm suspecting that the way volumes are mounted is incorrect but can't find why/how.

If anyone has any input on this it will be really useful :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it normal that your volume definition is empty?

Comment: Yep it can be empty, in this case you use the default driver. Basically this particular volume is properly mounted and accessible as the database properly start (and is getting accessible at the end of cloud build run command).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's an issue proper to `cloud-build-local`, properly works on GCP